# SMTP Server on C

Tags: c, sockets

I try to create a SMTP server on c and try it with FakeSmtp but I do not receive anything and i dont know why because the code is without warnings and error. Anyone can help me?
My whole code executed succesfully but i doesnt receive anything
OUTPUT is here:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP bh6sm124854736wjb.0 - gsmtp

DONE EHLO250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [85.98.184.204]

250-SIZE 35882577

250-8BITMIME

250-STARTTLS

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-PIPELINING

250-CHUNKING

250 SMTPUTF8

DONE EHLO AUTH451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821 bh6sm124854736wjb.0 - gsmtp

DONE AUTH

AUTH UID

DONE UID

AUTH PWD

MAIL FROM

MAIL TO

DONE MAILTO

DATASON DONE
```

The code:

```
void error(char *msg)
{
  perror(msg);
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int sockfd, portno, n;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
 struct hostent *server;

 char buffer[BUFFEr_SIZE];
 if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
 }
 portno = atoi(argv[2]);
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
     server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR connecting");

n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);

/*------------------------------*/
printf("\nDONE\n");
printf("EHLO");

strcpy(buffer,"ehlo smtp.gmail.com\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/    

/*------------------------------*/
printf("\nDONE EHLO\n");
printf("AUTH");

strcpy(buffer,"AUTH LOGIN\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/
printf("\nDONE AUTH\n");
printf("AUTH UID");

strcpy(buffer,"xxxx@gmail.com");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/
printf("\nDONE UID\n");
printf("AUTH PWD");

strcpy(buffer,"xxxxxx");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/

printf("MAIL FROM");

strcpy(buffer,"MAIL FROM: xxxxx@gmail.com");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/

 printf("MAIL TO");


strcpy(buffer,"RCPT TO: aaaaa@gmail.com");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);

/*------------------------------*/       

/*------------------------------*/
printf("DONE MAILTO\n");

printf("DATA");

strcpy(buffer,"DATA\r\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

strcpy(buffer,"Subject: test\r\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

strcpy(buffer,"SMTP MAIL TOOL TEST WORKS!!!\r\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

strcpy(buffer,"\n\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

strcpy(buffer,".\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));


/*------------------------------*/ 

/*------------------------------*/ 
printf("SON DONE");
strcpy(buffer,"quit\n");

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BUFFEr_SIZE-1);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
puts(buffer);

/*------------------------------*/

return 0;
}
```

Comment: First: lines MUST end in CRLF, See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/ Second: check the return value you get from write() and read(); it can be less than the 3rd argument. In practice, this means you need to buffer input and output.

Comment: Just a kind advice: If start learning TCP sockets better start with some less complex then a SMTP server. Try implementing a simple file-transfer server/client pair of programs which is able to transfer a large file (1Gb?) without any issues ... When you completed this successfully you know about the most basic pitfalls with TCP.

Comment: "*I try to create a SMTP server*" - no, you are not creating an SMTP server.  You are creating an SMTP client that connects to an SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement a protocol like SMTP it is recommended to have a look at the actual protocol standard instead of just guessing how the protocol works. In this case you are sending an `AUTH LOGIN` to the server even though the server did not specify any support for `AUTH` in the response to the `EHLO` command:

```
250-SIZE 35882577  
250-8BITMIME   
250-STARTTLS   
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES   
250-PIPELINING   
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

This is a violation of the SMTP protocol as the server as the server correctly argues:

```
451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821
```

Although, in this case the server is slightly wrong since `AUTH` is defined in [RFC 4954](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954) not RFC 2821.

In general the SMTP server for gmail.com does not offer authentication without TLS. This means you would first need to issue a `STARTTLS` command and check for a successful reply, then upgrade the socket to TLS and then you can issue `EHLO` again which then will show support for `AUTH`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:25 -starttls smtp
...
ehlo foo
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [92.117.36.90]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH   <<<< HERE
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

Comment: Also, the `EHLO` command must specify the *client's* own hostname, so the client can identify itself to the server.  Do not specify the server's hostname. The only place that is used is when looking up the server's IP address to `connect()` to.